# How can i keep the resolution of UIimage in coco2d in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, ccsprite

Hi i am working on image editing application using cocos2d. when i used to performs some action in cocos2d in on ccsprite i use to take screenshot of ccsprite and save it to preform the next effect.
But after each and every action performed the image of screenshot becomes more blur.
i want to keep the same resolution of image throughout so please if u have any idea to maintain resolution after each and every screen shot.
how to solve resolution problem?

u can email me on stackram1988@gmail.com.

Comment: you should provide the code you use to make the screenshot, the issue is there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi i am using this code to take screenshot

+(CCRenderTexture*) screenshotWithStartNode:(CCSprite *)startNode filename:(NSString*)filename
{
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

```
CGSize winSize = CGSizeMake(startNode.contentSizeInPixels.width, startNode.contentSizeInPixels.height);

CGSize   photoSize =CGSizeMake(startNode.contentSize.width, winSize.height * startNode.scaleX);
CCRenderTexture* rtx =[CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:startNode.contentSizeInPixels.width height:startNode.contentSizeInPixels.height];
[rtx begin];
```

[startNode visit];
    [rtx end];

```
// save as file as PNG
[rtx saveBuffer:[self screenshotPathForFile:filename]
         format:kCCImageFormatPNG];

return rtx;
```

}